# Combining two SELECT statements into one result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my DB. In one I have the Mailboxes, in other I have Aliases stored. To create a Dashboard I'd like to fetch some statistic data.

```
SELECT count(*) as postbox, sum(size) as size FROM users where email like '%@rootix.de'
```

and the other Query is going to be:

```
select count(*) as aliases from aliases where alias like '%@rootix.de'
```

As a result I want to have a single row with postbox, size and aliases. So I have to combine the two SELECT statements.

Something like

```
select count(*) as aliases from aliases where alias like '%@rootix.de'
```

didn't work for me, I've got "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" as an error.

I looked up, but found only pseudo solutions with an INNER JOIN by row number. Is this the only way to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, perhaps a bit brute force, would be to just use three separate subqueries in a single select:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%@rootix.de') AS postbox,
    (SELECT SUM(size) FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%@rootix.de') AS size,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS FROM aliases WHERE alias LIKE '%@rootix.de') AS aliases;
```

Comment: Thank you, looks at least better to me than the way with an inner join with row number as a "key".